# Issue in moving windows from one desktop to another with the compiz cube

Tags: gnome, compiz

After having installed compiz I made a reset then I have enabled:

- composite
- gnome compatibility
- openGL
- negative
- desktop cube
- expo
- rotating cube
- viewport switcher
- 3D windows
- cube reflection and deformation
- fading windows
- window decoration
- mouse position polling
- regex matching
- move window
  -resize window

Then the usual commands

```
alt+tab+shift+left/right
```

and

```
alt+tab
```

are not working anymore.

Any solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To move a window from one cube-face (desktop) use the right mouse button on windows title bar. (clicl-click-zoom   ⁛  ⁙ ⁘ ‧)

To switch windows use the "window buttons" on a panel ( I like the lower panel for this )

Consider getting the Compiz Fusion Icon and starting it up when starting your session.  It's extremely useful - note that it is invoked with the right mouse button when on the panel.

I use comiz cube and 3D windows in my work and have for a coupla years.  Their documentation is now much better, see it [here](http://wiki.compiz.org/CCSM).

I set cube face opacity during rotation to about 10 or 20, make the cube caps transparent and enable skydome to a muted gradient - with 3D windows this is very helpful in finding the right window.

Here's my desktop (without gradient skydome) [image]